# Multilabel Classification with scikit-learn and Probabilities instead of Simple Labels

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, multilabel

I'd like to classify a set of 3d images (MRI). There are 4 classes (i.e. grade of disease A, B, C, D) where the distinction between the 4 grades is not trivial, therefore the labels I have for the training data is not one class per image. It's a set of 4 probabilities, one per class, e.g.

```
0.7   0.1  0.05  0.15
0.35  0.2  0.45  0.0
...
```

... would basically mean that

- The first image belongs to class A with a probability of 70%, class B with 10%, C with 5% and D with 15%
- etc., I'm sure you get the idea.

I don't understand how to fit a model with these labels, because scikit-learn classifiers expect only 1 label per training data. Using just the class with the highest probability results in miserable results.

**Can I train my model with scikit-learn multilabel classification (and how)?**

Please note:

- Feature extraction is not the problem.
- Prediction is not the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Let me try to answer this, I will edit the answer as I have more information. In general scikit-learn does not provide classifiers that handle the multi-label classification problem very well. That's why I started the [scikit-multilearn's](http://scikit.ml) extension of scikit-learn and together with a lovely team of multi-label classification people around the world we are implementing more state of the art methods for MLC.

First of all, the question is do you need **probabilities** or just an estimate of how sure a classifier is. Not always the exact probabilities are what you can get very cheaply. I understand that you want to get  probabilities P(A|X), P(B|X) etc. for a given instance X.

**A.** The simplest case: **labels are indpendent** i.e. P(A and B|X)=P(A|X)P(B|X). If such case occurs you can use scikit-multilearns [Binary Relevance](http://scikit.ml/api/api/skmultilearn.problem_transform.html#module-skmultilearn.problem_transform.br) classifier's predict_proba:

here's a simple example with SVC as the per label probability estimator:

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
from sklearn.svm import SVC

classifier = BinaryRelevance(classifier = SVC(probability=True),
    require_dense = [False, True])

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
probabilities = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)
```

This will estimate per label probabilities and then renormalize them. Unfortunately Binary Relevance may fail to detect a rise/fall of probabilities in case when a combination of labels is mutually or even totally dependent, it just happens.

**B.** If your **labels are not independent** you need to explore the data set and ask yourself what is the level of co-dependence in your data. There are several ways to handle dependencies. If you really expect a total dependence, a Label Powerset approach may be better, where each combination is treated as a separate class and probability will be estimated per that class. Note that this transformation is a hard one to perform, due to label imbalances and the underfitting nature of Label Powerset transformation, I've created a solution for this to divide the label space into interconnected subspaces - a data-driven approach to detect dependencies and split the problem into interally more dependent subproblems - see [the data-driven approach to multi-label classification paper](http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/18/8/282).

An example how to use it is here: http://scikit.ml/api/classify.html#ensemble-approaches - just use predict_proba instead of predict. Also you might want to change the clusterer to:

```
clusterer = IGraphLabelCooccurenceClusterer('fastgreedy', weighted=True, include_self_edges=False)
```

so that the label partition is more granular. It detects clusters of co-occurring labels and then calculates joint distributions P(A1,...,An|X)  for labels A1...An per cluster, i.e. it expects the clusters of labels to independent.

If you like it and use this method please cite both the data-driven paper and the arxiv paper of scikit-multilearn, we can get funding to develop the library that way :) Also I'd love to know how the method worked for you so I can maybe improve it.

I find it easiest to just start with something, so if I were you, I'd go ahead and check the approach from point **A** and see what level of result you're getting. Then I'd try the label space partition approach. I need to write a tutorial on how to use it to explore the relations, will add this to my documentation todo list.

Comment: Thank you for these proposals and explanations. I will do as you suggest and tell you about the outcome.
Unfortunately, I don't have enough points to vote for your answer (yet).

Comment: Thank you!
My labels are **not** independent and therefore I replaced the classes by combinations of classes. As a proof of concept I did the pre-processing manually - with quite good results.
I will now automate it and find the optimal parameters, classifiers, etc.
As soon as I have the needed reputation, I will come back and vote for this answer.

Comment: You can use LabelPowerset classsifier for the simplest case if you don't have large numbers of labels.

Comment: @niedakh Did you address the requirement to model probabilistic labels? ie it's not just 1-hot encoded multi-label, it's a probability distribution across the labels...